# Project not up-to-date after building with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, aurelia

I'm a newbie to both IntelliJ and Aurelia. I did my last web project almost a decade ago, and I find myself a bit lost between all those new libraries. That said, my question is probably of rather trivial nature:

- I've downloaded the Aurelia skeleton project [1], imported the sources into a new node js project in IntelliJ and started index.html. Voila. Browser opens, shows the site.
- Then I changed something (added a new route to src/app.js). 
  I hit the run button to show index.html again: No changes. Hm?
- I rebuild the project in IntelliJ, and retried. Still my changes aren't shown.
- I run gulp watch on the command line, open the browser, and my changes are shown.

So, I'm asking two things: What needs to be done to really refresh the build within IntelliJ?

And secondly, when did it become a sport to create inter-depending Javascript libraries with blurry names? Just kidding... (though I'm not laughing)

[1] https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/src/child-router.js

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself. You need to put 'gulp build' to the pre-launch list of the run configuration. This is because the sources get transpiled and copied to the dist directory, from where the server is actually running.

Just building the sources from IntelliJ isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Project rebuild start automatically after any files was changed in project directory. You do not need to build it from IDE-- only save your changes and wait a few seconds to refresh.

Of cause it will work only when you run project build with `watch` statement like `gulp watch` (e.g. run gulp watch and your project will rebuild automatically).

But if there were some errors in code -- gulp process will stop and you must restart it again. I recommend you change IDE's settings to disable automatically saving to files and use `<CTRL+S>` buttons to save data manually.

Comment: I found it out meanwhile. When Intellij builds the sources, it doesn't store them in the dist directory. But that is from where the debug session is started... So I had to put 'gulp build' as pre-launch condition to the run config.